# Bundler is acting like a crazy person

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I accidently wrote `bundle update twitter` because I wanted to update the twitter gem. When I restarted the server (nginx with passenger) it yelled at me:

```
Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)) (process 31117, thread #<Thread:0x00000100887358>):
```

That was almost the end of my professional career as I contemplated suicide. But I'm on the first floor.

One `bundle install` later everything works perfectly, only: `Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./twitter`.

I'm using RVM. Everything was fine until now. How do I revert back to the old and comfortable situation  where the gems didn't sit inside my rails folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually ran `bundle install twitter`.
Run `bundle install --system` to reset it.

Comment: Or delete the line mentioning twitter from `.bundle/config` inside the project.

Comment: Thank you. May the good lord - all good lords - all dukes and princesses in the world praise your soul.